# Parse.com 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I need to push large arrays to my parse.com javascript application backend. Some arrays exceed 300 kb of text.  For these requests I am receiving 413 Request Entity Too Large errors, which makes sense.  How do I enlarge the POST size limitation for Parse.com requests? If I am unable to configure this the POST size, what is Parse.com's post limit so that I can efficiently split up the array into multiple submissions.

Also is there a limitation on the size of data to get from Parse?  Will I need to pull back this data with multiple requests? If so, how would I do this?  Is there option on Parse.Object.get for performing a multi-stage gets?

Edit : I see that the limit is 128 kB.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit for a ParseObject is 128kb.  You'll have to change how you're structuring this.

You can store data in another class/object and include a Pointer to that object on another object.  You can use the include method on a query to fetch that pointed-to object as well during a query.

Take a look through the query guide, specifically this section: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-relational

Comment: Thank for your reply.  The data is a flat array of many small json elements, so segmenting the data into parts to store in parse objects is probably not appropriate. Based on Fosco's response, I will just store the text as json files on s3 and reference the file in the parse object.

Comment: You can as well use the ParseFile to store.